# High availability HDFS client python

Tags: python, hdfs, webhdfs

In HDFSCLI docs it says that it can be configured to connect to multiple hosts by adding urls separated with semicolon `;` (https://hdfscli.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html#configuration).
I use kerberos client, and this is my code -
`from hdfs.ext.kerberos import KerberosClient hdfs_client = KerberosClient('http://host01:50070;http://host02:50070')`

And when I try to makedir for example, I get the following error - `requests.exceptions.InvalidURL: Failed to parse: http://host01:50070;http://host02:50070/webhdfs/v1/path/to/create`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the version of `hdfs` I installed was old, the code didn't work with version `2.0.8`, and it did work with version `2.5.7`